# Как прочитать и вывести все данные файла .pcap на языке C#

Tags: c#, pcap

С помощью библиотеки `pcapDotNeet` производится чтение файла `SV.pcap` но на выводе дает шестнадцатеричный код `(010CCD04000100306435445288BA...)`, подскажите как сделать чтобы данные выводились обычным текстом.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using PcapDotNet.Core;
using PcapDotNet.Packets;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;

namespace TestTasks
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            OfflinePacketDevice selectedDevice = new OfflinePacketDevice("SV.pcap");

            // Open the capture file
            using (PacketCommunicator communicator =
                selectedDevice.Open(65536,                                  
                                                                            
                                    PacketDeviceOpenAttributes.Promiscuous, 
                                    1000))                                  
            {
                
                communicator.ReceivePackets(0, DispatcherHandler);
            }
        }

        private static void DispatcherHandler(Packet packet)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i != packet.Length; ++i)
            {
                Console.Write(packet[i].ToString("X2"));

                    Console.WriteLine();*/
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `packet[i].ToString("X2")` - это же вроде и есть шестнадцатеричный код.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37020950/12888024 попробуйте код из вопроса

Comment: @aepot Если не использовать `ToString("X2")` то выводит десятичном виде

Comment: Ну вы странно вопрос поставили, выводите 16-ричный код и как бы удивляетесь этому "но на выводе дает шестнадцатеричный код". Внезапно.

Comment: Нет ничего лучше документации: [User Guide](https://github.com/PcapDotNet/Pcap.Net/wiki/User-Guide)